# Finding the residue of $e^{\frac {-3} {z^2}} $

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm going through past exam papers and came across the following question

find the residue of $f(z)=e^{\frac {-3} {z^2}} $ at $z=0$

I know how to find the residue and the residue theorem but I'm unsure how to find it for this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It's an even function. What does that say about its Laurent expansion around $0$?

Comment: Sum of residual is equal to 0. What ever is going to be the residual at 0 this is equivalent to get the residual to infinity and changing the sign.

Answer (score 0):

What about the usual Laurent (Taylor) series for the exponential?:

$$e^{-\frac3{z^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n3^n}{z^{2n}n!}\implies\text{ the residue is zero...as expected, since all the powers}$$

of $\;z\;$ are even.

Comment: The assertion $\lim_{z\to0}e^{-3/z^2}=0$ is wrong.  Try approaching $0$ from other directions in the complex plane.

Comment: @GEdgar That's what happens when you stand up in the middle of trying to answer a question: I completely forgot this was complex analysis. Deleting that part. Thanks