# Residue theorem and Cauchy's Integral Formula for $e^{\frac {-3} {z^2}} $

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Residue theorem and Cauchy's Integral Formula for $e^{\frac {-3} {z^2}} $

I'm looking at an exam question and one of the questions asks

find the residue of $f(z)=e^{\frac {-3} {z^2}} $ at $z=0$
which is equal to 0

however further on in the question it then asks to find the residue of

Evaluate $\int_Ce^{\frac {-3} {z^2}} dz$ where C is the unit circle.

Is this not simply just equal to 0 also?
Thanks

Comment: Indeed, the residue and thus the integral are both zero. This is coincidental, no theorems like Cauchy-Goursat are causing this.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2086047/finding-the-residue-of-e-frac-3-z2?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Well how did you define the residue? It s the first "negative" coefficient of the Laurent series expansion. You just have to use here the series expansion of the exponential function! =)